# MySQL Prompt Users to Reset Passwords during first login

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, password

I have this set of user accounts that I desire to create with default passwords then force the users to change passwords at first login. Plus, I wanted to force all user accounts to be resetting passwords after every 90 days. Is this supported in MySQL 5.7.x?

Answer (score 0):

All your questions are answered in [this documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-management.html)

To force a user to reset his password use `ALTER USER 'user'@'host' PASSWORD EXPIRE;`.

To force an expiration date of 90 days, either use `ALTER USER 'user'@'host' PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL 90 DAY;` for a single user, or set the variable [`default_password_lifetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_password_lifetime) to 90 for all users (you can exclude certain users by issuing a `ALTER USER 'user'@'host' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`).